# AWS unable to enforce https for S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I have tried several tutorials on how to set up https via CloudFront, but nothing is working. I am hosting from an S3 bucket and the app works fine via the http protocol, but I need it to be https.

Does anyone have a very thorough tutorial on how to make this work?

Some tutorials explain how to go about setting up a certificate, some explain how to use CloudFront to handle its distribution and I even found a CloudFront tutorial that explains how not using a link from the CloudFront setup forces the wrong region to be created for a certificate, so I even tried that.

I have not found anything that explains exactly what needs to be done for this very common setup, so I am hoping that someone here has some helpful resources.

Comment: Are you using a custom domain with CloudFront or serving from xxx.cloudfront.net?

Comment: I am using a custom domain

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue I had when setting up a CloudFront distribution for an S3 static webhosting bucket was in the **Orign Domain Name**.

When you create a new distribution, under Origin Settings, the **Origin Domain Name** field works as a drop-down menu and lists your buckets. Except that picking a bucket from that list doesn't work for static webhosting. You need to specifically put the **endpoint** for the bucket there, for example:

> *mywebhostingbucket.com.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com*

And for custom domains, you must set up the CNAMEs under Distribution Settings, **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)**, and *then* make sure you have your custom SSL certificate **in the us-east-1 region**.

Then you can configure the alias record set for the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: interesting...I will give this a try.

Comment: Still no luck. I think this is something that requires step by step instructions to make it work. Something is clearly missing. I tried the above, and now it's not even working with just http. Is anyone able to go through this thoroughly so that I can get an S3 bucket to work in https?

Comment: I guess I'll just bite the bullet and pay for their Developer support. Once I have a solution from them, I'll post it here so that others won't run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete answer for setting up a site with https.

I had everything in this document completed:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

And it worked to get the site live via http, but in order to add https, I needed to do the following:

I had requested a certificate for whatever.com, and tried several suggestions after that. But there were a couple of things missing.

To route traffic for the domain (whatever.com) to CloudFront distribution, you will need to clear the current value of the A record and fill in distribution domain name.

Several documents that I viewed said to point the whatever.com S3 bucket to the www.whatever.com S3 bucket, and use the second one to drive the site. Since CloudFront can serve multiple domain name, you may set CNAME of distribution with both, but you will need to set A record for both to distribution AND request an ACM certificate with both domain names (with and without the www). Also, I did ask this, so if you already have a certificate, you can't edit it to do this, which means you'll need to request a new one that has both whatever.com and www.whatever.com

After all of this, I still got "Access Denied" when I went to my site, so to fix this issue, I had to create a new origin in CloudFront with 'Origin Domain Name' set to the full address of the S3 bucket (without the http), and then set the Default (*) Behavior to the S3-Website-.....whatever.com bucket.

After all of this, my site was accessible via http AND https. I hope this helps anyone who experienced this challenge.